# Deploying a TopShelf windows service with Octopus Deploy fails consistently every second time

Tags: .net, octopus-deploy, topshelf

My setup is TeamCity -> Octopus Deploy and I have a .Net solution with a WebAPI and a windows service, the latter using TopShelf.

When I build I automatically deploy to a CI environment and do integration testing towards the CI env.

I use the custom OD steps for Uninstalling Topshelf Service and Installing Topshelf Service respectively.

The entire build fails however, when the integration tests do not succeed -- and this happends every second time, consistently, without any changes to code. Root cause being that the service can't be started. Every second time it can and all is good, everything is awesome!

I have found a work-around by inserting a Wait step of 30s between uninstalling and installing. Then it succeeds every time.

I should really like to not have a fixed delay in my deployment process -- when can I do?!

As always -- all comments welcome :)

Comment: Pretty vague.  But 30 seconds is a magic number, that is the default service controller timeout.  So maybe you are doing something *before* you start the service that is taking too long.

Comment: Thanks, Hans! Not quite a solution, but 'doing something before' triggered a thought : What if the deployment tasks could be switched? Now I (attempt to) stop service, then deploys the web API, and then finally start the service. And it works. Deploying the web API provides me 15s which appear to be suffiecent.
Still I'm wondering -- Why!?